# Can Reading buses short hop fares be paid by smart card?

Tags: buses, fares, england

[Reading buses](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk) has [smart cards](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/easysaver-10/) suitable for occasional travellers, typically loaded with ten trips.  They also have [short-hop fares](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/offers/) that are cheaper than the regular cash fares or regular smart card fares.  Is there any way to pay for short-hop fares by smart card, or can those only be paid in cash?

Comment: As I don't expect anyone on Travel Stack Exchange has an answer, I have asked [Reading buses](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/contact-us/) and will provide the answer here when they reply.

Comment: My experience of similar schemes in the UK suggests the answer is no. For both (2 types of) nottingham buses and one manchester bus, I know that "top uppable" cards don't do promotional fares

Comment: @CMaster I am suspecting the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An employee of Reading Buses answered my question:

> Thank you for your enquiry regarding our smartcards.
>
> If you are not a frequent traveller then you can opt for our E-Purse Card.  It doesn’t save you money, however will save you having to keep looking for correct change. Can be topped up online, with the driver or the shop.
>
> This can also be purchased online, or our Bus Shop in the Broad Street.

So, it does appear the answer is *yes*, with the special e-purse card.  On a closer look, the e-purse card is [described at their online shop page](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/online-shop-test/).

Presumably, you tell the bus driver upon entering to take only the short hop fare rather than the normal fare, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [smart card](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/smartcard/) information page from Reading buses? Your 'smart card' link in the question goes to the 'easysaver 10' (10 trip discount ticket) information page.

On the smart card info page in the section 'save money', they list which tickets you can top up the card with, namely 7, 30, 90 days or a yearly pass or the already mentioned 10 trip discount ticket, with each ticket covering a trip within the simplyReading zone.

Comment: Yes, I have.  The page does not address short hop fares, which my question is about.

Comment: It tells you which tickets you can top up the smart card with. SInce short hop tickets (and quite a few other tickets) are not on the list, shouldn't it be obvious that they are not available as an top up option for the smart card?

Comment: Assuming their website is complete, and assuming there are no other cards (for example, cards loaded with money rather than trips), that does follow.  However, elsewhere on the website it is mentioned that [children can get a](http://www.reading-buses.co.uk/solo/) *cashless card that you can put money on*.  Considering that this is not mentioned at the smart card page, the smart card page is clearly not complete, and it follows other information might be missing as well.